# Split string into 160-character chunks while adding text to each part

Tags: algorithm, strings, ruby

The `send_sms_message` method takes `text` as an argument. The length of `text` is unknown and can be 0 or as large as 10<sup>70</sup> (after that we will have no space for the actual text, because multi-part message text will be so long).

The trick is that if `text` is larger then 160 characters, we need to split it into parts and to each part add text part 1 of 2.

The problem is that we don't know the length of the extra text. It can be 14 characters for part 1 of 2 or 16 for part 11 of 99 and so on.

This code can handle up to 99 parts. How can I make it generic to handle more parts without adding more conditions?

```
SMS_LENGTH = 160
MPM_SIZE_LONG = 16
MPM_SIZE_SHORT = 14
MPM_SHORT_LIMIT = 1314

def send_sms_message(text, to, from)
  unless text.length > SMS_LENGTH
    deliver_message_via_carrier(text, to, from)
  else
    parts = text.scan(/.{1,#{SMS_LENGTH - (text.length > MPM_SHORT_LIMIT ? MPM_SIZE_LONG : MPM_SIZE_SHORT)}}/)
    parts.to_enum.with_index(1) do |message_part, index|
      deliver_message_via_carrier("#{message_part} - Part #{index} of #{parts.length}", to, from)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It's worth noting that your current code will make 159-character messages for the first 9 parts of a text with 10 or more parts, because " - Part 9 of 10" is only 15 characters.

Comment: @Aaron Yeah, I know we are wasting 1 byte here. But it is the tiniest problem here.

Comment: Sorry, without adding more conditions or changing your approach, I don't see a way to support more messages or eliminate the occasionally 1-byte difference. Regex and String.scan just aren't dynamic enough, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Aaron You are more than welcome to change the approach, this is why I posted code here.

Comment: Ah, when you said "without adding more conditions" I took that to also mean using this approach.

Comment: Your maximum text length can be 10^70 ? That's 10^67 times **more** than all the data humanity has stored since the 1980s.

Answer (score 2):

Some notes:

- Is your code inside a module or a class, I guess? You can include it in the question.
- As a general rule, favour the user of affirmative statements (`if` instead of `unless`).
- If you spend enough time with a pencil and a paper, maybe you'd get to a nice formula `get_total_parts(message_size, sms_size, parts_message_min_size)`, but it's not trivial, that's for sure. A pre-computing of the max_size (along with some extra info you'll need) is a bit tedious to write but fast. For example, what's the maximum size if you have a total count with exactly 3 digits (100-999)? `(SMS_SIZE - PARTS_MSG_MIN_SIZE - 2) * 9 + (SMS_SIZE - PARTS_MSG_MIN_SIZE - 3) * 90 + (SMS_SIZE - PARTS_MSG_MIN_SIZE - 4) * 900`. You get the idea.

I'd write:

```
module SMS
  SMS_LENGTH = 160

  PARTS_MESSAGE = " - Part %{n} of %{total}"

  SPLIT_INFO = (1..70).map do |ndigits|
    base_size = (PARTS_MESSAGE % {n: "1", total: "1"}).size 
    parts_per_digit = (0...ndigits).map do |n|
      (SMS_LENGTH - base_size - (ndigits + n - 1)) * (9 * (10 ** n))
    end
    {
      max_size: parts_per_digit.reduce(0, :+), 
      size_of_first_parts: parts_per_digit[0...-1].reduce(0, :+),
      min_parts: 10**(ndigits - 1) - 1, 
      msgsize_for_last_parts: (SMS_LENGTH - base_size - 2 * (ndigits - 1))
    }
  end

  def self.get_total_parts_for_long_message(text)
    info = SPLIT_INFO.detect { |h| text.size <= h[:max_size] } or 
      raise ValueError("Message text too large")
    info[:size_of_first_parts] + 
      Rational(text.size - info[:min_size], info[:msgsize_for_last_parts]).ceil
  end 

  def self.send_sms_message(text, to, from)
    if text.length <= SMS_LENGTH
      deliver_message_via_carrier(text, to, from)
    else
      total_parts = get_total_parts_for_long_message(text) 
      idx = 0

      (1..total_parts).each do |part_index|
        split_message = PARTS_MESSAGE % {n: part_index, total: total_parts}
        user_message_size = SMS_LENGTH - split_message.size
        message_text = text[idx, SMS_LENGTH - user_message_size]
        deliver_message_via_carrier(message_text + split_message, to, from)
        idx += user_message_size
      end
    end
  end

  def self.deliver_message_via_carrier(text, to, from)
    puts("Sending #{from} -> #{to}: #{text} - #{text.size} bytes")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The splitting isn't trivial. Therefore I wouldn't rely on `scan()` and regular expressions. I would first compute the count of sms and then use a text stream via `StringIO` and the pull the text.

Here is the first trial of the implementation.

```
def send_sms_message(text, to, from)
  count = split_count(text)
  if count == 1
    deliver_message_via_carrier(text, to, from)
  else
    text_stream = StringIO.new(text)
    1.upto(count).each do |n|
      suffix = " - Part #{n} of #{count}"
      content = text_stream.read(160 - suffix.length) + suffix
      deliver_message_via_carrier(content, to, from)
    end
  end
end

def split_count(text)
  rest_length = text.length
  count = 0
  while rest_length > 0
    count += 1
    case count
    when        1 then rest_length -= 160
    when        2 then rest_length -= 160 - 14 - 14
    when     3..9 then rest_length -= 160 - 14
    when       10 then rest_length -= 160 - 16 - 9
    when   11..99 then rest_length -= 160 - 16
    when      100 then rest_length -= 160 - 18 - 99
    when 101..999 then rest_length -= 160 - 18
    end
  end
  count
end
```

The complex part is the computation of the `split_count`. The trial version has room for improvements.

- You could compute the magic numbers by computations. For example the length of the `suffix` could be calculated with `14 + 2 * Math.log10(count).floor`. Maybe the whole `case` expression could be a function which returns the decrease value for `rest_length`.
- You could use memoization/caching for performance.
- You could take look at [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) which was my inspiration for the implementation.

**Update**

I removed the magic numbers by constants and functions. Here is my final solution without any optimizations.

```
SMS_LENGTH = 160
SUFFIX_TEMPLATE = ' - Part %d of %d'

def send_sms_message(text, to, from)
  count = split_count(text)
  if count == 1
    deliver_message_via_carrier(text, to, from)
  else
    text_stream = StringIO.new(text)
    1.upto(count).each do |i|
      suffix = render_suffix(i, count)
      content = text_stream.read(SMS_LENGTH - suffix.length) + suffix
      deliver_message_via_carrier(content, to, from)
    end
  end
end

def split_count(text)
  rest_length = text.length
  count = 0
  while rest_length > 0
    count += 1
    rest_length -= payload_size(count)
  end
  count
end

def render_suffix(i, count)
  format(SUFFIX_TEMPLATE, i, count)
end

def payload_size(nth)
  case nth
  when 1 then SMS_LENGTH
  when 2 then SMS_LENGTH - 2 * render_suffix(nth, nth).size
  else SMS_LENGTH - render_suffix(nth, nth).length - (is_power_of_10?(nth) ? nth - 1 : 0)
  end
end

def is_power_of_10?(n)
  Math.log10(n) % 1 == 0
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in software you should alter the requirements to simplify the life of everyone (including the business people presumably asking for this to be done).

I would push back against the requirement to pre-calculate the total number of messages. Rather than pre-calculating utilize an **end of message** marker instead (the text `END` should suffice).

I used the solution below to simulate sending [an entire book](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/19002/pg19002.txt) via SMS, and it required fewer than 700 messages total.

---

For example, if you changed your message format to exclude the "... of X" portion, and did the following instead:

```
<msg part    > - Part 1
<msg part    > - Part 2
...
...
...
<msg part> - Part 12657
END
```

... then your implementation becomes much more straightforward (though even this sample implementation should be cleaned up):

```
MULTIPART_SUFFIX = ' - Part '

def deliver_message_via_carrier(text, to, from)
  puts text
end

def send_sms_message(text, to, from)
  chars = text.chars
  counter = 0

  if text.length <= 160
    deliver_message_via_carrier(text, to, from)
  else
    while chars.length > 0
      counter += 1
      suffix_text = "#{MULTIPART_SUFFIX}#{counter}"
      msg_part = chars.shift(160 - suffix_text.length).join('')

      deliver_message_via_carrier("#{msg_part}#{suffix_text}", to, from)
    end
    deliver_message_via_carrier('END', to, from)
  end
end

send_sms_message(text, :sender, :receiver)
```

...and you get the following benefits:

- Can send messases of arbitrary length (though let's be honest - you'll probably never send more than 1,000,000 messages, so supporting messages of length 10^70 -- many, many times the total amount of data that all of humanity has ever stored -- is highly dubious).
- Your message suffix is shorter, so you wind up saving many characters per message, resulting in many fewer total messages for any message you're likely to actually send.
- This alternative format allows you to easily make every partial message exactly 160 characters in length, which is more efficient on a per-message basis.
- Your code's logic is much simpler, and therefore easier to maintain.
- Messages are still able to be sorted on the receiving end if necessary (i.e. if they are received out-of-order for some reason), because they are individually numbered.